# Build parameter array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do this:

```
$.getJSON("myscript.php", {0: info[0].value, 1: info[1].value, 2: info[2].value ......});
```

How do I build a loop to create the second object (the parameters)? I've tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
var n = info.length;
var params = new Array();
for(i=0; i<n; i++) params[i] = info[i].value;
$.getJSON("myscript.php", params);
```

The resulting GET to myscript.php becomes `myscript.php?undefined=&undefined=&...`

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to do `$.getJSON("myscript.php, { data: params });`. Then in PHP `$_GET['data']` will be the array.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) about the `data` parameter: *"A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request."*. An array is neither a plain object nor a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `params` as an object instead of an array

```
var n = info.length;
var params = {};
for(i=0; i<n; i++) params[i] = info[i].value;
$.getJSON("myscript.php", params);
```

If you want array to work

```
var n = info.length;
var params = new Array();
for(i=0; i<n; i++){ 
    params[i] = {
        name: i, 
        value: info[i].value
    }
};
$.getJSON("myscript.php", params);
```

Comment: Great, that works. Thank you. By the way, why doesn't the array work?

Comment: @Eric Maybe for the array to work, you need to push items to it: `params.push(info[i].value);`? As @ArunPJohny and @FelixKling pointed out, though, you have to use an object.